# nodejs router.route contains all async middle ware, is the router itself async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a router that runs several middlewares. So it looks like this.

router.route("/").get(something, something_else, one_more_thing)

the functions something, something_else, one_more_thing are all async. and "one_more_thing" returns a response.

does this mean the entire router.route() is async. Or do i need to switch it to something like,

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await something
    await something_else
    results = await one_more_thing
    res.json(results)
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
});
```

UPDATE:: Adding actual code

Here is my router.route call

```
    router.route('/clock_in').post(timeClockValidator, isManager, startingOnTime, isClockedIn, clockIn);
```

Here is timeClockValidator

```
export const timeClockValidator = async (req, res, next) => {
  logger.info('validating time clock json.');

  let schema = '';
  let results = { errors: [] };

  req.originalUrl === '/api/timeclock/clock_in'
    ? (schema = time_clock_schema)
    : (schema = schema);

  try {
    results = await v.validate(req.body, schema);
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(error);
    return res.status(400).json('Error");
  }

  return results.errors.length !== 0
    ? (logger.error(results.errors),
      res.status(400).json("Error")
    : next();
};
```

The rest of the functions are set up the same way.

Comment: it just means that routes callback function is async.. the code you supplied should work and is what i'm referring to.

Comment: is the first code snippet fine then?

Oh but since i'm using this router.route in my server.js, and since router.route is not async, that means every time i run that specific route i block the thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nodejs router.route contains all async middle ware, is the router itself async?

Yes, if any part of any middleware or handler involved in processing an incoming request is asynchronous, then the result will be delivered asynchronously (on some future tick of the event loop).  "Asynchronous" is often referred to as "infectious" in that once anything in a chain of code is asynchronous, then the whole result becomes asynchronous because once any part of the chain is delayed to a future tick of the event loop by any part of the chain, then the final result will always be delayed to some future tick of the event loop.

It's kind of like taking a trip that involves getting on four different trains.  If one train breaks down and you're stranded for 24 hours, then you're going to be at least 24 hours late on all subsequent trains in your trip too.

There's a difference between a middleware function that uses asynchronous operations and a plain `async` function that isn't specifically designed to be a middleware function.

To do something like:

```
router.route("/").get(something, something_else, one_more_thing)
```

Both `something` and `something_else` have to accept arguments such as `(req, res, next)` and they have to call `next()` when they are done in order to continue on to the next handler in the list for this route.  They can be either synchronous or asynchronous as long as they either call `next()` when they are done to advance to the next middleware or send a response and stop further routing by not calling `next()`.

That requires a completely different function than running things like this:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await something
    await something_else
    results = await one_more_thing
    res.json(results)
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
});
```

If `something()` and `something_else()` return promises as this implies, then you cannot use these functions in the first form - you would only be able to use them like this.

So, this is why I strongly dislike these theoretical questions without pseudo-code and no real code (they are less productive for everyone).  If you show us some ACTUAL code for `something()` and `something_else()`, then we could see exactly how they are written and could advise you either how to fix them to work in one of these forms or could advise exactly which form they work with.

Comment: currently something() and something_else() do take req, res, next and they call next() or they return a res if there was some issue.

Maybe it's just bad design on my part then and i should change something() and something_else() to be more inline with the second example.

Comment: @PhilipJayFry - Then they would ONLY work in the first form (where the express infrastructure treats them as middleware and would not work at all in the second form.  Also, it does nothing useful to `await` a function that doesn't return a promise.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that piece, i'm just curious as to what is better.Maybe they're both fine?

Comment: @PhilipJayFry - Well, the same functions won't work in both scenarios.  Are you asking if you rewrite `something()` and `something_else()` to return promises and then use them in the second form?

Comment: Sorry I may not have been clear in my question. I'm trying to decide which way is better I don't want to block the event loop. 

if the event loop remains unblocked in the first example with router.route then it should be fine

however if the fact that router.route itself is not asyc blocks the event loop, then i'd rather rewrite all my code now to avoid problems in the future.

I have a server.js file that is calling router.route if that matters. The js file router.route lives in has a bunch of other routers as well, so my server.js imports the 1 file, and can handle multiple calls.

Comment: @PhilipJayFry - The choice between these two designs does NOT affect blocking the event loop in any way.  You are off on the wrong idea there.  Blocking the event loop has to do with running synchronous code that takes a little time to run.  It doesn't matter whether it's structured in middleware or in an `async` function.  Either way, a long running piece of synchronous code blocks the event loop.  Please show some REAL code and then I can stop guessing what you're trying to ask about.

Comment: @PhilipJayFry - AND, if you really meant to ask about blocking the event loop, why didn't you make that the main part of your question?  Please ask the actual question you are working on, not some side question about some possible solution to the main question.  That process here is called the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and should be avoided because it really gets in the way of you getting the best possible help/answers here and us understanding what the real question/problem is.

Comment: thanks for the replies. I added some of my code above. All of the functions are written the same way. I think what you added to your original comment answers my question however.

Comment: @PhilipJayFry - Well `timeClockValidator()` only works properly in the first form (as an actual middleware function).  It will not work the second way.  If it was rewritten to work the second way, that would not change how the event loop is or isn't blocked at all.

Comment: FYI, this `req.originalUrl === '/api/timeclock/clock_in'
    ? (schema = time_clock_schema)
    : (schema = schema);
` is really bizarre code.  You can simplify that.

Comment: Correct, totally understand that. As you pointed out I asked the question poorly. I was really trying to see if one was blocking the event loop and once wasn't. If one was then i'd change it so it wasn't. My thinking was asyc does not block the event loop, but that could be wrong.

Comment: @PhilipJayFry - Because node.js runs your Javascript in a single thread, however much time some of your code takes to run is how long the event loop is blocked for and it doesn't matter whether it's in a regular function or in an `async` function.  Either way, node.js can't process other events while it's running your code (event loop is blocked).  Now, when your code calls some built-in asynchronous operation such as a timer or a network request or an asynchronous file operation, then while you are waiting for the completion callback, the event loop is not blocked.

Comment: @PhilipJayFry - But, that's only with built-in asynchronous operations that have native code behind them in order to implement true asynchronous (background) operation that makes progress independent of the main JS thread where your JS runs.  You can't write a new completely asynchronous operation yourself without using some native code in a nodejs add-on.

Comment: thanks for the replies I really appreciate it. I'm newer to nodejs and you seem pretty great at it. If you have any book recommendations i'd love to know.

Comment: @PhilipJayFry - I learned everything I know about node.js by doing three things: 1) Reading and attempting to answer questions here, 2) Writing code for my own projects and researching things I needed to solve for those and 3) Searching on the internet and reading articles about issues I needed to learn about.  I have not owned or read any books on node.js.

Comment: @PhilipJayFry - I can add a fourth thing: 4) Looking at the [source code for node.js libraries](https://github.com/nodejs/node).